# How to keep track of dates/times in Android/java

Tags: java, android

This may be a simple question for some of you and I may just be missing something but I wanted to ask if anyone knew how to keep track of events that happened at specific times of the day or days of the week for android in java. The same way that Google Calendar can put in any event for something to happen at some time at someday and when that time comes they were alert you. except I'm not using Google's API or even a UI. I'm basically trying to create an Android app (with java)  that I can set something to happen at a time and day so for example at Tuesday at 3 p.m. something happens. Then Thursday at 4 something else happens. Im not sure if the app should watch the system clock and at every minute check for the event or if app itself should have a running timer for every minute to check for that date to hit or is there a better way. Any help would be appreciated. I thought of using google apis but the ones i found are ones connected to calendar and I wanted this to be independent of that

Comment: Did you already look into [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)?

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example) post

Comment: Your Question talks both about past-tense and future. Clarify.

Comment: Search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting.

Comment: @0X0nosugar that won't work for me in this case

Comment: @FlyingNades I asked about this and I was told it wont work for my case

Comment: @Basil Bourque Basically future task, and i could not find what no was looking for on stackoverflow.

Comment: Then please edit your post to explain why the linked "original" is not helpful and then we can try to get the question reopened